# Ruby on Rails implement Ajax Post and Comments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Someone could help me? Im trying implement the AJAX to my project and what i need to do should be very easy but for me becomed a madness days rsrs.
My ideia is when the user add new comment shoud appear
without reload page, below follow my controller, views and routes. Ahh to delete i did something that worked.

## here is /app/controller/comments_controller.rb

[image]

## Post app/controller/posts_controller.rb

[image]

## Views Comments /app/views/comments/_template.html.slim

[image]

## Views Comments /app/views/comments/_form.html.slim

[image]

## Views Pots /app/views/posts/show.html.slim

[image]

## Solution to dele comment used

[image]

Comment: How about using $.ajax, send the comment text to your controller, validate it, respond true if valid. Upon receiving true, $(comment-holder).append(the new comment)..      Oh, you're looking for the $.ajax syntax?.

Comment: I`m trying something like this 
jQuery ->
  # Create a comment
  $(".comment-form")
    .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .addClass('uneditable-input')
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .removeClass('uneditable-input')
        .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .val('');
      $(xhr.responseText).append($("#comments_container")).show('slow')

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of a snapshot?

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, from now on I will post only text code.

Answer (score 0):

```
create.js.erb

$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "comments/template", collection: @post.comments, as: :comment) %>");

_template.html.erb
<p class="comment-name"><%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user_id)%>
  <span class="comment-content"><%= comment.content %></span> 
</p>
<p class="comment-time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>

CommentsController

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js 
    end 
end
```

**This might be too simplistic but maybe it will spark something.**

Comment: Just to be more clear, I`m using gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading',  the comment controller can be used in any other model, and the solution that you gave me will change the way the things are working. thank you.